# How many Pixel for this print?

Tags: photoshop, printing, resolution

I need to make a Drawing in photoshop. This drawing will be printed on a 2A0 size (double the A0), and will have lots of names on it. The smalles ones will be about 2cm in height. Then in a later moment this image will be Printed on A1 size and the smallest names will be printed in about 5mm height.

The A1 version should be crisp and sharp while reading it at about 50 cm away. The 2A0 verison will be seen at about 1 Meter distance.

What resoultion should my photopshop project have in order to meet the requirements and print at the proper sharpness?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be in any way related to photography, but graphic design.

Comment: Sounds more like a [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) problem to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On average, young people can distinguish about 10 pixels/mm @ 30 cm. So for an optimal result viewed at 30 cm, on A1 (594×841 mm) you'd need a final image of 5940×8410 pixels.

As the A1 will be watched from 50 cm, your required image size would go down by a factor of 3/5, which gives an image size of **3564×5046** pixels.

The same size in pixels will work for the 2A0: you multiply each side by 2, and double the viewing distance.